# How to reuse scenarios to run across an upgrade of my product platform?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

The following scenario runs in v1 of the software.
The v2 product is being revamped and has a complete new dashboard

The only changes are "Login v2" and "Open Grid v2" which could contain different set of steps and rest of the functional scenarios remain the same.

How should I model my scenarios so that I can reuse my existing scenario definitions, while running the tests in v1 as well as v2.

I am using selenium Web driver.

```
@Create
Feature: Create Orders

  Scenario: Login v1
    Given I navigate 
    And I enter user name
    And I enter password
    And I login

  Scenario: Open Grid v1
    Given I choose menu
    And I choose Orders menu

  Scenario: Scenario1

  Scenario: Scenario2

  Scenario: Scenario3
```

Comment: You can make it configurable via command line with fig_newton, or with a tag hook in the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Dave is right.  You can use additional tags, e.g. @v1only, @v2only, to control which scenarios execute.  You can specify the tags at execution time (e.g.

```
@CucumberOptions(tags = {"@sometest","~@v1only"}) // run all @sometag that is not also tagged as @v1only
```

You can have different @Before("@v1only") ...  and @Before("@v2only") blocks to control, on a scenario by scenario basis, what setup and tear-down, @After("@v1only") ... and @After("@v2only") ...  steps are executed based on tags.  Scenarios that work in both would omit the only tags.  It is doable.